# Android: call specific-version API

Tags: android, api

My application ( started on Android 2.3.3 ) has also to support the Android Ice Cream OS 4.0.3.
All works fine but the query from Content Resolver makes strange things with the round parenthesis when GROUP BY is used and the SQL complains about that giving a crash. The same is not seen with Android API level 10.
That said, here my question: is it possible to use old version or the API ( 10 in my case ) also on the Ice Cream?
Of course if there is a better solution to my problem it will be welcomed.

Thank in advance.

The code ( a simplified version ) is the following one:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath( ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, "");
StringBuilder where = new StringBuilder();
allContactCursor = contentResolver.query( uri,
PROJECTION_CONTACT,
"1) GROUP BY ( "+ RawContacts.CONTACT_ID,
null,
ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE");
```

The problem is that the Ice Cream Sandwich doesn't allow the GROUP BY injection while compiling the Sqlite query, this, instead, works on Gingerbread 2.3.3.
Without GROUP BY the contacts are duplicated depending on the number of phone numbers a contact has.

Thanks

Comment: Not really. There's one version on the device. Regarding your problem, it will help if you show the code and the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.+ is backwards compatible, so it should run your application fine even if it using android 2.3.3 api.  Unless you are using api features that are specific to 4.0.  Your best bet is to build your application to 2.3.3 then test it on ICS 4.0... I hope this helped

Comment: Hi I know the Android does set compatibility flags when an app compiled against a old API level is executed on a more recent one. I've already done what you suggested and the problem I've described is seen.